# slide left and slide right using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hi friend m trying to make a menu bar which will slide to left or right. This navigation bar is controlled by two arrow if user mouse over on the right arrow then the navigation will move right to left till the end and when it reach its last point so it will be stop. Same thing will happen  when user mouse over on left arrow the navigation will move left to right and when its reach last point then it will stop sliding

I don't know how to assemble all the things together please check fiddle here **http://jsfiddle.net/DdkLS/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="arrowLeft"><</div>
  <div class="arrowRight">></div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">why us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background: #C00;
    position: relative;
}
.nav .arrowLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav .arrowRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 23px;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var leftMove = 0;   
        var rightMove = 0;  
        var leftValue = $('.nav').find('ul').css('left');           
        var rightValue = $('.nav').find('ul').css('right'); 
        var rightNumeric = parseInt(rightValue);
        var leftNumeric = parseInt(leftValue);
        alert(rightNumeric);

    $('.arrowLeft').mouseenter(function(){              
        setInterval(function(){
            if(rightNumeric < 0)
            {
                leftMove = leftMove+10;
                $('.nav ul').animate({left : '-'+leftMove+'px'},1);     

            }
            if(rightNumeric > 0)
            {

                $('.nav ul').css('left','-'+rightNumeric+'px');     

            }
        },1)


        })

        $('.arrowRight').mouseenter(function(){             
        setInterval(function(){
            if(leftNumeric < 0)
            {
                leftMove = leftMove+10;
                $('.nav ul').animate({left : ''+leftMove+'px'},1);      

            }
            if(rightNumeric > 0)
            {

                $('.nav ul').css('left',''+rightNumeric+'px');      

            }
        },1)


        })
```

Please help me guys .. Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.arrowLeft').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.nav ul').animate({ left: '+=120' }, 400 );
});

$('.arrowRight').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.nav ul').animate({ left: '-=120' }, 400 );
});
```

**NOTE:** You need to manage space before moving `left` or `right`, i have just give a hint here.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qYmr/2/)

**UPDATE**

It's better to use jQuery plugin for that, take a look at this

1. http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/
2. http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/
3. http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for help ... but i want to slide this countinuesaly until <ul> reaches its last 0

Comment: You should use jQuery plugins for that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right you're looking for something like this - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DdkLS/25/)

As you have a limiting width wrapper .nav(width=940px) around your ul, we calculate its width and shift ul to the right with this value minus first child.

```
  shift = $(wrapper).width() - $(li).first().width();
```

For moving to the left, we need to move the slider by the actual ul width minus last child width.

note, that i've changed the css property for ul width (I set it to 99999px), this is to make sure the floated lis do not go to another line.